# Loop all values in client.guilds, then loop all members in each guild

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a moderation bot and I'm trying to solve an issue I have where when the bot stops/restarts/crashes if a user is muted then they will be permanently muted until manually unmuted. I need to loop all guilds the bot is in and save its id to a variable, as well as loop all members in that guild and save their id to a variable as well. I have tried `.forEach()` but I get `client.guilds.forEach() is not a function` any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should be `client.guilds.cache.forEach()` or `client.guilds.cache.each()`.

Comment: Try running `console.log(client.guilds)` to see what it contains. It may be that `guilds` is not an array.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros thank you that worked

Comment: Why is Nadelvorhang's answer accepted? It looks like it has the same problem as in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```js
let guildsID = [];
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    guildsID.push(guild.id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its client.guilds.**cache**.forEach

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildManager

client.guilds is a GuildManager, not an iterator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).